# Screen Resolution issue with Metro app when running in local machine (Windows 8 desktop)?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, screen-resolution

Hi I am developing a Windows 8 C# / Xaml Metro application. I have taken grid template project and customized to my design requirement.

When I am testing the application in Windows 8 simulator it works fine, but when I run the application in Windows 8 desktop using VS2012 local machine option I am facing many problems.

If I am using standard resolution of 1366 * 768 it works fine.
If I am using a low resolution like 1280 * 720 etc (low end resolutions), the screen shrinking in many cases and it causes many problem, including irregular and inconsistent look.

My doubt is:

1. As per my knowledge is that Metro unique feature is to scale/render in different resolutions in same way, then why is it not able to achieve it properly?
2. Am I missing anything very important regarding Windows 8 Metro screen resolution?
3. How to make the Metro app work in different resolutions of desktop in same way and give a consistent look?

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This MSDN article is an excellent source on how to scale your app: 
[Scaling To Different Screens](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx)

Points from the article that may be relavent to you:

- The minimum screen resolution for an app is 1024 x 768.  Your resolution above (1280 x 720) does not meet this minimum.
- For the grid graphics - it may help if you provide the suggested sizes of (100%, 140%, and 180%).  For example, for the standard grid size (250 x 250), you should provide images of the sizes of 250 x 250 (100%), 350 x 350 (140%), and 450 x 450 (180%). You have to use one of the two naming schemes (file name scheme, or folder name scheme) for your app to automatically select the size.  For example, if your graphic in the xaml is named "mygraphic.jpg", then you can provide the scaled images named "mygraphic.scale-100.jpg", "mygraphic.scale-140.jpg", and "mygraphic.scale-180.jpg".
- Since you are not very specific in indicating what is wrong, it is hard to suggest other things.  Definitely take a look at the article.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your content panel in a Viewbox.  It will scale the content to fill the available space.